# AngularJS fixed list with updating content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im in need of some inspiration on how to solve the following:

I'm making an information monitor using AngularJS.

The monitor should list a maximum of 6 rows of information.

A new row will always be put on top of the others and pushed in from the top. If there are already 6 rows, the last row will be pushed out from the bottom.

A row may disappear from the list at any given time.

Visually, I would very much like it to be sort of scrolling, so when a new row is to be displayed, it will slide in from the top, and all the items will slide a row down.

I'm not sure how to implement the above. I've thought about ng-repeat, but I don't know how to move the items when an element appears or is deleted.

I hope somebody can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add new item in top list, use a unshift method of javascript. For example:

```
var list = [0,1,2]
list.unshift(3)
// results  [3,0,1,2]
```

remember, add and remove items in $scope of list for update her.

```
$scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$scope.list.unshift(9); // [9,1,2,3,4,5,6];
$scope.list.pop(1);     // [9,2,3,4,5,6];
```

In HTML, continue using ng-repeat normally

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look at ngAnimate. It has built-in support for working with ng-repeat including animations on the addition and deletion of items from a list.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

The docs for the integrations with ngRepeat are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm gonna look into that.